# Application unwantedly diverts to main activity before intent activity

Tags: java, android, mysql

I am using this code for extracting ID from a mySql database. The connection strings work perfectly. The application suddenly goes to the main class(MainActivity.class) for a few seconds before going to the intent activity(FinalActivity.class) mentioned in the code. The LogCat also mentions a case of "leaked window" in the code.

```
 class GetID extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

            boolean failure = false;

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                pDialog2 = new ProgressDialog(DashboardActivity.this);
                pDialog2.setMessage("Attempting...");
                pDialog2.setIndeterminate(false);
                pDialog2.setCancelable(true);
                pDialog2.show();
            }

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
                int success;
                try {
                    // Building Parameters
                    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("SerialToRefer", Serial1));

                    Log.d("request!", "starting");
                    JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                            LOGIN_URL2, "POST", params);

                    Log.d("Login attempt", json.toString());
                    success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
                    if (success == 1) {
                        GetID = json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
                        Log.d("Login Successful!", GetID);
                        Intent intent = new Intent(DashboardActivity.this, FinalActivity.class);
                        intent.putExtra("Serial1", Serial1);
                        intent.putExtra("GetID", GetID);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        return "Please wait...";
                    }

                    else{
                        Log.d("Login Failure!", json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE));
                        return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);

                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                finally{}
                pDialog.dismiss();
                pDialog = null;
                return null;
            }
            protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
                try {
                      pDialog2.dismiss();
                      pDialog2 = null;
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                    }
                if (file_url != null){
                    Toast.makeText(DashboardActivity.this, file_url, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                finish();
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Do inBackground is running on an AsyncTask.  So it will be run at some point in the future, when the OS schedules it.  Until that thread is scheduled, it will not start the FinalActivity.  So yes, the activity that this thread is running in will appear first.

That isn't even mentioning the fact this thread makes an HTTP request, which will take a few seconds.  So you can't go directly to the FinalActivity anyway.

Comment: Actually a good point.  Would mean that where ever you are calling this Async Task from, is the default or current activity.  Moving to the final only happens after your internet activity is Successful

Comment: Is there a method to show a splash screen during the internet activity?

Comment: A method to do so automatically?  No.  But its a common pattern, google should be able to find a few example implementations.

Answer (score 0):

Looks good to me.  I am wondering if the problem is in the manifest.  Did you copy & paste the entry for the FinalActivity?